# iOS 6.1 UIWebview crashes when clicked on play youtube video inside a webpage

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6

I am trying to show a website inside app. The website which i am trying to load has got a youtube video in it. The website loads properly in UIWebView and also lists the youtube video. But when I click on youtube video, the app crashes.

Crash log just says:

```
setting movie path: http://r19---sn-aig7knl7.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?...............
```

The website when loaded in Safari works fine, it even plays youtube video full screen.

Please help me in fixing this issue.

***11 Feb 2013 - UPDATE***

**The issue is observed only on iOS Simulator 6.1. On Device everything works fine.**

***Detailed Info:***

I have a custom UIViewController(TestWebViewController) which has an instance of UIWebView and implements UIWebViewDelegate. I have added a UIViewController in Storyboard and added UIWebView inside it, linked this UIViewController to my custom TestWebViewController and linked IBOutlet and delegate for UIWebView.

On Clicking a button, I am programmatically instantiating TestWebViewController using

```
TestWebViewController *testWebVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testWebVC"];
testWebVC.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[testWebVC loadWebViewWithUrl:TEST_URL];

[self presentViewController:testWebVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Please show the code where you create the webview, and also any webview delegate methods you have implemented.

Comment: Emil, Added code used. And also added observation that this issue is seen only on iOS Simulator 6.1 and everything works fine on device.

Comment: I got a similar error somewhat randomly, but it went away for me on the simulator when I removed my breakpoint for all exceptions. Did you have any breakpoints enabled?

Comment: Scott, Yes that is right. I had Exception breakpoints enabled. It works on simulator when the exception breakpoints are removed.

Comment: Same here. Removing the exception breakpoint removes the crash when I play my YouTube video on the simulator. Thanks. What gives? Is there an exception that I should be dealing with?

Comment: do you set escape character encoding for the url.?

Answer (score 3):

As scott said in his comment, I removed my breakpoint for all exceptions and my error went away.

Hope this will help to others.

Answer (score 0):

Modal view on iOS 5.0 and iOS 5.1 is the problem that causes crash on full screen video, AFAIK. They just changed hierarchy of views in that version of iOS (parentViewController and presentingViewController) and that is the aftermath. I asked about it long time ago here and one more same question is here and still no one knows what to do.

First of all, they fixed it in 6.0, I guess, that's good.

For 5.1 we changed design a little and avoided modal view. Do it, if it is possible in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
    TestWebViewController *testWebVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testWebVC"];

[testWebVC LoadWebView:@"YOUR URL STRING"];
[self presentViewController:testWebVC animated:YES completion:nil];

 AND in TestWebViewController class

-(void)LoadWebView:(NSString *)address {
addressStr = address;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
url = [NSURL URLWithString:addressStr];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] ;
[myWebView loadRequest:request] ;
}
```